# How do I stop the cardlayout .next() and .previous() from looping

Tags: java, swing

I have here a sample of a program here. I have 3 panels and I want to stop the user in pressing the previous button if the panel is in `panel_1` and also stop at the end of `panel_3` which is that last panel. Is there any way to like disable the button if the user is at the start of the panel or at end of the panel?

```
package cardlayoutalignment;

  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
  import javax.swing.border.Border;
  import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class gridbaglayoutdemo {
JFrame Card = new JFrame();

FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,2,2);
Border etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray);
Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);

public static GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
final static boolean shouldFill = true;

JPanel container = new JPanel();
JPanel divider = new JPanel();
JPanel bodypanel = new JPanel();
final JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

public gridbaglayoutdemo(){

    Card.setVisible(true);
    Card.setSize(605,333);
    Card.setTitle("");
    Card.setResizable(false);

    final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
    int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - Card.getWidth())/2);
    int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - Card.getHeight())/2);

    Card.setLocation(x, y);
    Card.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


    bodypanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    divider.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    container.setLayout(cl);
    cl.show(container, "1");

    panel_1.setLayout(grid);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Enter 1:");
    label_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_1.add(label_1, c);

    JComboBox box_1 = new JComboBox();
    box_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_1.add(box_1,c);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    panel_1.add(label, c);


    panel_2.setLayout(grid);

    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Enter 2:");
    label_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_2.add(label_2,c);

    JTextField text_2 = new JTextField();
    text_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_2.add(text_2,c);

    JLabel label_22 = new JLabel("");
    label_22.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    panel_2.add(label_22, c);


    panel_3.setLayout(grid);

    JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Enter 3:");
    label_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_3.add(label_3,c);

    JTextField text_3 = new JTextField();
    text_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
    panel_3.add(text_3,c);

    JLabel label_33 = new JLabel("");
    label_33.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
    panel_3.add(label_33, c);

    buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    buttonpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,10,0,0));

    JButton btnBack = new JButton("< Back");
    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        cl.previous(container);
        buttonpanel.repaint();
        }   
    });
    btnBack.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnBack.setFocusable(false);
    btnBack.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    btnBack.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnBack.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    btnBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
    btnBack.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    buttonpanel.add(btnBack);

    JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next >");
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cl.next(container);
            buttonpanel.repaint();
        }   
    });
    btnNext.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnNext.setFocusable(false);
    btnNext.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    btnNext.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnNext.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    btnNext.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
    btnNext.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    buttonpanel.add(btnNext);

    final JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Window dialog = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( btnCancel );
            dialog.dispose(); 
        }   
    });
    btnCancel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    btnCancel.setFocusable(false);
    btnCancel.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    btnCancel.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnCancel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    btnCancel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
    btnCancel.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    buttonpanel.add(btnCancel);

    JPanel numberpanel = new JPanel();
    numberpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(221,0));
    numberpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,0,0,10));
    numberpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray));
    numberpanel.setLayout(flow);

    JButton button_7 = new JButton("7");
    button_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_7.setFocusable(false);
    button_7.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_7.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_7.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_7.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_7);

    JButton button_8 = new JButton("8");
    button_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_8.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_8.setFocusable(false);
    button_8.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_8.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_8.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_8.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_8);

    JButton button_9 = new JButton("9");
    button_9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }   
    });
    button_9.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    button_9.setFocusable(false);
    button_9.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    button_9.setFocusPainted(false);
    button_9.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
    button_9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
    button_9.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
    numberpanel.add(button_9);



    Card.add(bodypanel);
        bodypanel.add(divider, BorderLayout.WEST);
            divider.add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);     
                container.add(panel_1, "1");
                container.add(panel_2, "2");
                container.add(panel_3, "3");
                //container.add(panel_4, "4");
                //container.add(p5.panel_5, "5");
                //container.add(p6.panel_6, "6");
            divider.add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        bodypanel.add(numberpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
  }

   public static void main(String[] args){
     //Use the event dispatch thread for Swing components
     EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
     {
    @Override
     public void run()
     {
     new gridbaglayoutdemo();         
     }
     });

     }
 }
```

Sorry for the not so short working code. I already trimmed some of it. That's the shortest ver I can do.

Comment: `That's the shortest ver I can do.` - no the code is way to long. Your question is about the buttons, not the data on the panels. So all you need to do is add a JLabel to each tab to represent multiple tabs. Then you just add the "Next" and "Back" buttons. All the other buttons and components are irrelevant to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Is there any way to like disable the button if the user is at the start of the panel or at end of the panel?"*

According to [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and [CardLayout API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) there's no direct way to do it.

But you can implement this feature easily keeping an int variable with current card number and checking its value againts 0 (for first card) or container's component count (for last card). For instance:

```
public class GridBagLayoutDemo { // note code convention!

    int currentCard = 0;
    Action backAction, nextAction;
    ...

    public GridBagLayoutDemo() {
        ...
        backAction = new AbstractAction("< Back") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentCard--;
                GridBagLayoutDemo.this.evaluateActions();
            }
        };

        nextAction = new AbstractAction("Next >") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                currentCard++;
                GridBagLayoutDemo.this.evaluateActions();
            }
        };

        JButton btnBack = new JButton(backAction);
        ...
        JButton btnNext = new JButton(nextAction);
        ...
    }

    private void evaluateActions() {
        backAction.setEnabled(currentCard > 0);
        nextAction.setEnabled(currentCard < container.getComponentCount() - 1);
    }
    ...
}
```

---

### Addendum

Looking closer at `CardLayout` implementation, it would be really easy to have this feature implemented by default (unless I'm missing something):

```
public class CardLayout implements LayoutManager2,
                                   Serializable {

    /*
     * This creates a Vector to store associated
     * pairs of components and their names.
     * @see java.util.Vector
     */
    Vector vector = new Vector();

    /*
     * Index of Component currently displayed by CardLayout.
     */
    int currentCard = 0;

    ...

    /* 
     * Hypothetical implementations
     */

    public boolean isDisplayingFirstCard() {
        return currentCard == 0;
    }

    public boolean isDisplayingLastCard() {
        return currentCard == vector.size() - 1;
    }
}
```

Don't know why they didn't provide such useful feature.

Comment: You should use an Action instead of ActionListener and then just disable the Action. Any component the Action is added to will be disabled. Also, any time a button is clicked you need to determine/reset the state of both buttons. ie. clicking on "Next" you will need to enable the "Back" button, so your Action will need access to both buttons, not just the button that was clicked.

Comment: Thanks @camickr, I'll update my answer with your suggestions as soon as I can. Yours is a great example (as usual), +1 for that!

Comment: @dic19 Hi! I have implemented your code and it works now. But I have a slight problem. When I run the program the currentCard starts with 1 instead of 0 so I can still click the back button but if you scroll throughout until the end it'll get normal. I don't know why is it like that.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you have a different problem, please post a new question including your code (better if it's a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) so anyone can help you. @user3771102

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Card Layout Actions](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/01/card-layout-actions/) for a simple extension of the `CardLayout`.

It provides **"Next"** and **"Previous"** actions that you can use to create buttons or menu items and the Actions will automatically be disabled when you are at the end/beginning of the cards.

Comment: Hi @camickr . I have checked the link and I don't know how to implement those methods.

Comment: @user3771102, There is nothing to implement. All you do is 1) download the RXCardLayout class and 2) create the buttons and add them to a panel. I gave example code how to use the class. The 3 lines of code that build the "south" panel show the basic code.

Comment: Oh I see. Okay. I'll check it again. :)

Comment: Hi @camickr ! I have done exactly what you said and the buttons are disabled. I don't know why.

Comment: @user3771102, `the buttons are disabled. I don't know why` - me either. It's 3 lines of code and you haven't posted your code showing how you are using the RXCardLayout. I'm guessing you are using the CardLayout and not the RXCardLayout.