# Is there a difference where I run my program?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

Regarding to my question I have before [How to stop .next() and .previous() from looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866220/how-do-i-stop-the-cardlayout-next-and-previous-from-looping) It seems that whenever I cancel/finish/close my jframe I can't make my original program run again like when I run it for the first time.

I made the code below in netbeans while my original code is in eclipse. There shouldn't be difference where I run my program, right? But then.. I have that code in my original program in eclipse and it only execute `.setEnable` and `.setText` only once when I run my program. Even though both of the platforms have the same code I get different outcomes. Is this natural or not? My code below works perfectly fine but then in my original code it isn't. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Should I post a snippet of codes from my original code for comparison?

This is my sample code though its not that short...

main class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
*
* @author lenovo
*/
public class main {
    JFrame Card = new JFrame();
    public main(){

        Card.setVisible(true);
                        Card.setSize(605,333);
                        Card.setTitle("Tank Delivery");
                        Card.setResizable(false);

                        final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                        Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
                        int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - Card.getWidth())/2);
                        int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - Card.getHeight())/2);

                    Card.setLocation(x, y);
                    Card.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                    JButton a = new JButton("OPEN");
                    a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            gridbaglayoutdemo g = new gridbaglayoutdemo();
                        }
                    });
                    panel.add(a);

                    Card.add(panel);
    }



            public static void main(String[] args){
            //Use the event dispatch thread for Swing components
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new main();         
            }
        });

        }
}
```

my other class:

```
    package cardlayoutalignment;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

    public class gridbaglayoutdemo {
            JFrame Card = new JFrame();

            FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,2,2);
            Border etch = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray);
            Border margin = new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);

            public static GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            final static boolean shouldFill = true;

            JPanel container;
            JPanel divider = new JPanel();
            JPanel bodypanel = new JPanel();
            final JPanel buttonpanel = new JPanel();
            JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
            JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
            CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

            JTextArea text_2;
            JTextArea text_3;


            String change = "Finish";
            final JButton btnNext;
            final JButton btnBack;
            int currentCard = 0;
            int cardflag = 0;

            AbstractAction backAction;
            AbstractAction nextAction;

        public gridbaglayoutdemo(){

                    Card.setVisible(true);
                    Card.setSize(605,333);
                    Card.setTitle("Tank Delivery");
                    Card.setResizable(false);

                    final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
                    int x=(int)((dimension.getWidth() - Card.getWidth())/2);
                    int y=(int)((dimension.getHeight() - Card.getHeight())/2);

                Card.setLocation(x, y);
                Card.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


                bodypanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                divider.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                container = new JPanel(cl);
                container.setLayout(cl);
                cl.show(container, "1");

                panel_1.setLayout(grid);

                JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Enter 1:");
                label_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 0;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 0;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
                panel_1.add(label_1, c);

                JComboBox box_1 = new JComboBox();
                box_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 0;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 1;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
                panel_1.add(box_1,c);

                JLabel label = new JLabel("");
                label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 1;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 2;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
                panel_1.add(label, c);


                panel_2.setLayout(grid);

                JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Enter 2:");
                label_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 0;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 0;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
                panel_2.add(label_2,c);

                text_2 = new JTextArea();
                text_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 0;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 20;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
                panel_2.add(text_2,c);

                JLabel label_22 = new JLabel("");
                label_22.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 1;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 30;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
                panel_2.add(label_22, c);


                panel_3.setLayout(grid);

                JLabel label_3 = new JLabel("Enter 3:");
                label_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 0;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 0;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
                panel_3.add(label_3,c);

                text_3 = new JTextArea();
                text_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,30));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 0;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 20;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,0);
                panel_3.add(text_3,c);

                JLabel label_33 = new JLabel("");
                label_33.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                    c.weightx = 0.5;
                    c.weighty = 1;
                    c.gridx = 0;
                    c.gridy = 30;
                    c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
                panel_3.add(label_33, c);

                buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.RIGHT));
                buttonpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,10,0,0));


                buttonpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.RIGHT));
                buttonpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));

                    btnBack = new JButton("< Back");
                    btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    cl.previous(container);
                                    buttonpanel.repaint();
                                    cardflag--;
                                    if (cardflag==0)
                                    {btnBack.setEnabled(false);}
                                    if(cardflag<3)
                                    {btnNext.setText("Next >");}
                            }   
                    });
                    btnBack.setEnabled(false);
                    btnBack.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                    btnBack.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                    btnBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
                    btnBack.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
                buttonpanel.add(btnBack);

                    btnNext = new JButton("Next >");
                    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    cl.next(container);
                                    buttonpanel.repaint();

                                    cardflag++;
                                    if(cardflag<3)
                                    {btnBack.setEnabled(true);}
                                    if(cardflag==2)
                                    {btnNext.setText(change);}
                                    if (cardflag==3)
                                    {cl.show(container, "3");
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DONE");
                                    Window dialog = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( btnNext );
                                    dialog.dispose(); 
                                    cardflag=0;
                                    btnNext.setText("Next >");
                                    }

                                    validateText();


                            }   
                    });
                    btnNext.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                    btnNext.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                    btnNext.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
                    btnNext.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
                    btnNext.setVisible(true);
                buttonpanel.add(btnNext);

                    final JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
                    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                cardflag=0;
                                    Window dialog = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( btnCancel );
                                    dialog.dispose(); 
                            }   
                    });
                    btnCancel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                    btnCancel.setFocusable(false);
                    btnCancel.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
                    btnCancel.setFocusPainted(false);
                    btnCancel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                    btnCancel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 40));
                    btnCancel.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
                buttonpanel.add(btnCancel);

                JPanel numberpanel = new JPanel();
                numberpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(221,0));
                numberpanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,0,0,10));
                numberpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.white,Color.gray));
                numberpanel.setLayout(flow);

                    JButton button_7 = new JButton("7");
                    button_7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            buttonaction(e);
                            }   
                    });
                    button_7.setActionCommand("7");
                    button_7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                    button_7.setFocusable(false);
                    button_7.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
                    button_7.setFocusPainted(false);
                    button_7.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                    button_7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
                    button_7.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
                numberpanel.add(button_7);

                JButton button_8 = new JButton("8");
                    button_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            buttonaction(e);
                            }   
                    });
                    button_8.setActionCommand("8");
                    button_8.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                    button_8.setFocusable(false);
                    button_8.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
                    button_8.setFocusPainted(false);
                    button_8.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                    button_8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
                    button_8.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
                numberpanel.add(button_8);

                JButton button_9 = new JButton("9");
                    button_9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            buttonaction(e);
                            }   
                    });
                    button_9.setActionCommand("9");
                    button_9.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                    button_9.setFocusable(false);
                    button_9.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
                    button_9.setFocusPainted(false);
                    button_9.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.BLACK, null, null, null));
                    button_9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 70));
                    button_9.setBackground(new Color(224,223,227));
                numberpanel.add(button_9);



                Card.add(bodypanel);
                    bodypanel.add(divider, BorderLayout.WEST);
                            divider.add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH);     
                                    container.add(panel_1, "1");
                                    container.add(panel_2, "2");
                                    container.add(panel_3, "3");

                            divider.add(buttonpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    bodypanel.add(numberpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        }

            private void buttonaction(ActionEvent e){
                try{
                if(cardflag==1)
                    {text_2.append("" + e.getActionCommand());}
                if(cardflag==2)
                    {text_3.append("" + e.getActionCommand());}

                }catch(Exception e1){}
            }

            private void validateText(){
                if(cardflag==2)
                {String text = text_2.getText();
                    if (text.isEmpty()==true)
                    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Text 2 is empty!");
                    cl.show(container, "2");
                    btnNext.setText("Next >");
                    cardflag--;
                    }
                }
            }



    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson The problem is my short version of the code is working perfectly fine. I can't replicate the error I'm getting from my original code.

Comment: You need to discover the difference between the short program that works, and the longer one that doesn't.  I doubt anyone here will be able to guess the difference based on the available information.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I guess you're right. Maybe the longer one is much complicated than the shorter one. I'll try to change my code to another to make it work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome for the little help I could offer.  If you discover the source of the problem, please write up an answer.